# How to pull information for 20k email addresses from an Active Directory?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, ldap

I'm trying to go through 20k employee email addresses to pull information from an Active Directory.

The code worked with a single email typed out in the code. I'm trying to go through all the emails in a single column list and return values in an adjacent column in Excel.

Example:
Email Address: chuck.norris@us.navy.mil
Desired Outlook Title Return: NORRIS, CHUCK P KARATE USNC 318 COBRA/KAI

I also tried these lines:
`ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = gigIDldap(4, True, Range("B1"))`
`ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A3").Value = gigIDldap(4, True, Range("B2:B3"))`

The first one referencing a single cell works. The second one referencing a range of cells doesn't. I verified that email addresses are in cells B1 to B3.

```vb
Dim userinfo(15) As Variant
Sub TEST()
'call function as follows: <VARIABLE> = gigIDldap(<INDEX>, True, <EMAIL>)
'Available indexes:
'userinfo(0) = .givenName
'userinfo(1) = .Initials
'userinfo(2) = .LastName
'userinfo(3) = .personalTitle
'userinfo(4) = .DisplayName
'userinfo(5) = .userPrincipalName
'userinfo(6) = .o
'userinfo(7) = .sAMAccountName
'userinfo(8) = .mail
'userinfo(9) = .physicalDeliveryOfficeName
'userinfo(10) = .telephoneNumber
'userinfo(11) = .l
'userinfo(12) = .c
'userinfo(13) = .Title
'userinfo(14) = .Department
'userinfo(15) = .company
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = gigIDldap(4, True, "Chuck.Norris@us.mail.mil")   **<---- This line works**

ActiveSheet.Range(“A1:A5”).Value = gigIDldap(4, True, Range(“B1:B5”)) **<--- This is my attempt at looking up 5 emails and returning the values in 5 adjacent cells. It does not work.**
End Sub

Function ADaddress()
    'This script can determine the AD directory required for LDAP queries
    Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
    Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)
    dname = objUser.distinguishedName
    DLoc = InStr(dname, "DC=")
    ADaddress = Right(dname, Len(dname) - DLoc + 1)
End Function

Public Function gigIDldap(infoIndex As Integer, useEmail As Boolean, Optional mail As String, Optional gigid As String) As Variant
    Dim AFDS As String
    Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2
    If gigid = "" Then gigid = "1"
    If userinfo(8) = mail Or userinfo(7) = gigid Then
        gigIDldap = userinfo(infoIndex)
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
    Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
    objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1
    objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE
    AFDS = ADaddress()
    'setup AFDS query
    If useEmail Then
        objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM 'LDAP://" & AFDS & "' WHERE objectCategory='user' AND mail='" & mail & "'"
    Else
        objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM 'LDAP://" & AFDS & "' WHERE objectCategory='user' AND gigid='" & gigid & "'"
    End If
    Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
    If objRecordSet.RecordCount = 0 Then
        gigid = ""
        Exit Function
    Else
        objRecordSet.MoveFirst
    End If
    Set objUser = GetObject(objRecordSet.Fields("ADsPath").Value)
    With objUser
        userinfo(0) = .givenName
        userinfo(1) = .Initials
        userinfo(2) = .LastName
        userinfo(3) = .personalTitle
        userinfo(4) = .DisplayName
        userinfo(5) = .userPrincipalName
        userinfo(6) = .o
        userinfo(7) = .sAMAccountName
        userinfo(8) = .mail
        userinfo(9) = .physicalDeliveryOfficeName
        userinfo(10) = .telephoneNumber
        userinfo(11) = .l
        userinfo(12) = .c
        userinfo(13) = .Title
        userinfo(14) = .Department
        userinfo(15) = .company
        'Debug.Print userinfo(12)
    End With
    gigIDldap = userinfo(infoIndex)
    'available fields for objUser:
'    With objUser
'        Debug.Print .adminDescription
'        Debug.Print .adminDisplayName
'        Debug.Print .altSecurityIdentities
'        Debug.Print .buildingName
'        Debug.Print .c
'        Debug.Print .cn
'        Debug.Print .codePage
'        Debug.Print .company
'        Debug.Print .countryCode
'        Debug.Print .delivContLength
'        Debug.Print .Department
'        Debug.Print .directReports
'        Debug.Print .DisplayName
'        Debug.Print .distinguishedName
'        Debug.Print .dLMemDefault
'        Debug.Print .employeeID
'        Debug.Print .employeeType
'        Debug.Print .extensionAttribute13
'        Debug.Print .gigid
'        Debug.Print .givenName
'        Debug.Print .homeMDB
'        Debug.Print .homeMTA
'        Debug.Print .iaTrainingDate
'        Debug.Print .Initials
'        Debug.Print .instanceType
'        Debug.Print .l
'        Debug.Print .legacyExchangeDN
'        Debug.Print .logonCount
'        Debug.Print .mail
'        Debug.Print .mailNickname
'        Debug.Print .Manager
'        Debug.Print .mDBOverHardQuotaLimit
'        Debug.Print .mDBOverQuotaLimit
'        Debug.Print .mDBStorageQuota
'        Debug.Print .mDBUseDefaults
'        Debug.Print .MiddleName
'        Debug.Print .msExchALObjectVersion
'        Debug.Print .msExchDelegateListBL
'        Debug.Print .msExchELCMailboxFlags
'        Debug.Print .msExchExtensionCustomAttribute1
'        Debug.Print .msExchHideFromAddressLists
'        Debug.Print .msExchHomeServerName
'        Debug.Print .msExchMailboxGuid
'        Debug.Print .msExchMDBRulesQuota
'        Debug.Print .msExchPoliciesExcluded
'        Debug.Print .msExchRBACPolicyLink
'        Debug.Print .msExchRecipientDisplayType
'        Debug.Print .msExchSafeSendersHash
'        Debug.Print .msExchUMEnabledFlags2
'        Debug.Print .msExchUserAccountControl
'        Debug.Print .msExchUserCulture
'        Debug.Print .msExchWhenMailboxCreated
'        Debug.Print .Name
'        Debug.Print .o
'        Debug.Print .objectCategory
'        Debug.Print .objectGUID
'        Debug.Print .objectSid
'        Debug.Print .payGrade
'        Debug.Print .payPlan
'        Debug.Print .personalTitle
'        Debug.Print .physicalDeliveryOfficeName
'        Debug.Print .PostalCode
'        Debug.Print .primaryGroupID
'        Debug.Print .replicatedObjectVersion
'        Debug.Print .replicationSignature
'        Debug.Print .roomNumber
'        Debug.Print .sAMAccountName
'        Debug.Print .sAMAccountType
'        Debug.Print .sIDHistory
'        Debug.Print .sn
'        Debug.Print .st
'        Debug.Print .street
'        Debug.Print .StreetAddress
'        Debug.Print .submissionContLength
'        Debug.Print .telephoneNumber
'        Debug.Print .textEncodedORAddress
'        Debug.Print .Title
'        Debug.Print .URL
'        Debug.Print .userAccountControl
'        Debug.Print .UserCertificate
'        Debug.Print .userPassword
'        Debug.Print .userPrincipalName
'        Debug.Print .userSMIMECertificate
'        Debug.Print .whenChanged
'        Debug.Print .whenCreated
'    End With
End Function
```

Comment: What does it do *instead* of work?  Are you getting an error or?

Comment: FYI `“B1:B5”` has "smart quotes" which are not the same as regular quotes...

Comment: I also just tried this one:
Range("B1").Select
      ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = gigIDldap(4, True, Cells(1, 2))
   ' Insert your code here.
         ' Step down 1 row from present location.
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop
   End Sub

All this does is do the first line, then it jumps down to the end of the list. It doesn't progress and repeat for the next cell in the next row

Comment: Post a screen shot of what you have and what your desired outcome is. Right now this looks like a bad homework assignment that took a turn for an attempt at being a cool action movie, but in the end is still a bad homework assignment.

Comment: I wish it was just a class assignment as I'd take a C than staying up to 11 each work night learning how to do VBA in prep for a HHQ report due next Wednesday. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU6DE.png.   I just want VBA to use the email in B1 and spit out the value in A1, then use the value in B2 for the VBA code, then spit out the value in A2. Column B has email addresses that are used in VBA LDAP code to obtain a DisplayName from the Active Directory